# Global listener for value

Tags: angularjs

In my AngularJs app I want a global way to call a factory when a value changes.

The value is `$scope.loading`

So in a controller when I set `$scope.loading = true;` 
the *"global listener"* will call the factory `progressFactory.start();`

When I set `$scope.loading = false;` in the controller I want the *"global listener"* to call the factory `progressFactory.complete();`

Please answer with code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$watch`

```
$scope.$watch("loading", function(value) {
    if (value) progressFactory.start();
    else progressFactory.complete();
});
```

Comment: Is this listener global for all controllers in the app? Or is it a solution for a single controller? Is it possible to listen for two values at once, for example when both `$scope.gotData1 = true` and `$scope.gotData2 = true` then I can set `$scope.loading = true`?

Comment: This is only for a single controller, use `rootScope` to catch events across all controllers.

Comment: Okay, but in the controller. Can I modify your code to work for two (or more) different values. So when I am loading from multiple data sources I could do this: When `$scope.gotData1 = true` and `$scope.gotData2 = true` then I can set `$scope.loading = true`

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
$rootScope.$on("event", function(event, myValues)
```

And when you have to call that:

```
$rootScope.$emit("event", myValus);
```

Another solution is to use

```
 $rootScope.$watch
```

Comment: Thanks! I am new to angular. Could you be a bit more specific where to place it and use my value `$scope.loading` in the example. Otherwise I won't figure it out.

Comment: The $rootScope.$on has to be used within the controller (so it can reach the $scope).
The $rootScope.$emit can be put in any service/controller/directive you want.